# pulling information from specific fields in Rails 4 Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am creating a Blog Post Versioning System. (I tried Paper_trail and Draftsman and they don't have what I need).  When a user Edits a "live" Page, instead of changing the live version, my app makes a PostVersion table entry with the new information and calls it "pending". HOWEVER, if the user  Edits a "draft" page, NO "pending" PostVersion is created, it just edits the page directly.

I can't seem to get the form params to pass from the form to the PostVersion.create! method. It just submits nil values when I'm trying to pull from the form values.

posts_controller.rb

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.status == 'draft'
   #this not important
  end
  if @post.status == 'live'
    @pending_post =  PostVersion.create!(title: params[:title], status:  'pending',  body: params[:body],  post_id:  @post.id )
  end
end
```

_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @post ], multipart: true do |f| 
  = f.error_notification 
  = f.input :title, label: 'Title', required: true, focus: true
  #rest of the form redacted
```

Comment: pretty sure your form params is nested inside "post", you can always check it in server logs, if that is the case then you should pass it as params[:post][:title], so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual params may be nested under a "post" array of sorts, such as `post[title]`. You might want to define a specific params method like so:

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.status == 'draft'
   #this not important
  end
  if @post.status == 'live'
    @pending_post =  PostVersion.create!(title: post_params[:title], status:  'pending',  body: post_params[:body],  post_id:  @post.id )
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit :title, :body
end
```

Comment: I get this error "There is an Error: undefined local variable or method `post_params'  probably because I'm trying to create a PostVersion using the information from a form used to edit a Post (I do have strong params set on both)...I tried using post_version_params and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the strong params method you're using?